# Accessing Microsoft's expression blend training videos

Tags: expression-blend

Every time I go to a video like [this one](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565835.aspx), my browser says it is "temporarily unavailable."  Have those videos been taken down?  Is there any way I can access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened, but they work now.